# PHP-FPM and CHROOT

Tags: lighttpd, php

I'm using Lighttpd and php-fpm, I would like to chroot the vhost of each website.

The pages of the website are in: **/home/vhosts/example1.com/web**

each vhost has the same layer:

```
/home/vhosts/example1.com/web
/home/vhosts/example2.com/web
/home/vhosts/example3.com/web
```

I used this kind of path as document-root of the domain (example1.com), I don't know what psychical path I should use to chroot the vhost, I tried:

```
document-root = /web

chroot = /home/vhosts/example1.com/ (on php-fpm.conf file)
```

but I always get 404 NOT FOUND error. How can I chroot the vhost?

(Each website has .php and .html pages.)

Answer (score 1):

In lighttpd.conf:

```
server.document-root = "/home/vhosts/example1.com/web"
fastcgi.server = (
  ".php" => (
  "localhost" => (
     "docroot" => "/web",
     "socket" => "/home/vhosts/example1.com/php.socket",
   )
  )
)
```

In fpm.conf:

```
listen = /home/vhosts/example1.com/php.socket
chroot = /home/vhosts/example1.com/
```

Comment: @konforce ?? I'm using an IP ADDRESS on the listen option like: 127.0.0.1:9001 (fpm.conf) and I don't set the socket but the IP address on fascgi.server

Comment: @konforce, do you mean i can use IP:PORT instead of php.socket you wrote?

Comment: @Dail. In `lighttpd.conf` you'll use `host=` and `port=` and in `fpm.conf` you'll use `listen=ip:port`

Comment: @Dail, good to hear. Keep in mind that some PHP functions might need external files to work properly. For example, spell checking probably needs the dictionary files. In those cases, you'll have to copy (or hard link) whatever files you need from `/usr/blah` into `/home/vhosts/example1.com/usr/blah`. Most things work just fine, but if some functions aren't working, that's the first thing you should check.

Comment: @konforce yes, correct! aah the last thing konforce... on my php-fpm.conf file I set slowlog = /home/vhosts/example1.com/log/php-slow.log Will I have problem with it? this is outside the /web directory, also the path for this log will be chrooted ? THank you really much again!

Comment: @Dail, I'm not sure, but I think it will be chrooted too. Should be easy to test and see.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$prefix` & `$pool` variables in fpm.conf to simplfy configuration for multiple chroots

```
[example1.com]
prefix = /home/vhosts/$pool/
listen = $prefix/php.sock
chroot = $prefix

[example2.com]
prefix = /home/vhosts/$pool/
listen = $prefix/php.sock
chroot = $prefix
```

You may want to use [TCP / IP to listen](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/fpm-sysctl-tweaking/) insted of sockets for a fast growing site as it's more stable than using unix sockets

Don't forget to limit to limit TCP connections by IP address:

```
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```